# If $J$ is totally ordered with $|J| \leq |\mathbb{R}|$, is there an injection from $J$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: set-theory

If $J$ is an infinite totally ordered set with $J$ of cardinality less than that of $\mathbb{R}$, is there an injection from $J$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that preserves order? (I believe it exists, but do not know about set theory. This is relevant to my dissertation.)

If it exists, is it possible for the range of the injection to be unbounded above?

Comment: Your title says  $|J|\leq |\mathbb{R}|$, but the body says "$J$ of cardinality less than that of $\mathbb{R}$", which I would interpret as $|J|<|\mathbb{R}|$. Which do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, the first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  For example, suppose $J$ is uncountable and well-ordered.  Then there is no order-preserving injection from $J$ to $\mathbb R$, because no uncountable subset of $\mathbb R$ is well-ordered (with the standard order on $\mathbb R$): see e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order)

Answer (score 3):

Consider $\mathcal{O} = \mathbb{R} \times \{0,1\}$ with the lexicographic order, that is $(\alpha, i) \prec (\beta, j)$ if $\alpha < \beta$ or $\alpha = \beta$, and $i=0$, $j=1$. In this set $\mathcal{O}$ we have uncountably many pairs of   intervals $[\alpha, 0), (\alpha, 1) ]$. If these did lie in $\mathbb{R}$ in the same order in $\mathbb{R}$ the in each of them we could place a different rational number, contradiction.

Idea: the induced partial order on $intervals$ in $\mathbb{R}$ does not contain uncountable chains.